# In Visual Studio can I run the Performance Profiler on a specific unit test?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, performance-testing

I would like to see where I have bottle necks in a specific method. I believe that this is input dependent (a specific set of inputs will cause a much longer run time than others). I already have unit tests exploring the various input possibilities.

Is there a way for me in Visual studio to get the `Debug > Performance Profiler` to run on a specific unit test the same way I would debug a specific test (`Test Explorer > Right Click > Debug`)?

Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.7

Comment: Could you state/tag the appropriate version of Visual Studio

Comment: @phuzi I just added it.